# Geometry proof question : with triangle ABC with angles 30,60 and 90

Tags: geometry

∠A = 30◦ ∠B = 60◦ ∠C = 90◦ With the knowledge of the Pythagorean theorem only, I have to prove that when point D, at the middle of the hypotenuse, connects to point C, it divides the triangle into two triangles: an equilateral and an isosceles.

I have drawn the triangle in front of me and I have absolutely no idea how to start.

Edit 1 : Since the angle ∠A is 30degrees, then the triangle DCA has to be the isosceles one. This means the side DA and DC have the same length. This also means that the sides BD, BC AND DC are all the same length because that makes the equilateral triangle. So to sum it up, segments BC. BD, CD, AND DA should all have the same length. What should I do now?

[Here is an image to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htZpx.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way of seeing it is:

-Because of the angles:
$$AC=\cos(30º)BC=\sqrt{3}AB/2$$
$$BC=cos(60º)BC=AB/2$$
-Because of the position of $D$:
$$AD=BD=AB/2$$
-Using the median formula for $DC$:
$$DC=\sqrt{2(AC^2+BC^2)-AB^2}/2=AB/2$$

So the triangle $\{B,D,C\}$ has sides with equal length ($DB=DC=BC=AB/2$)-> equilateral. The triangle $\{A,D,C\}$ has two sides that are equal ($AD=DC=AB/2$) so it is isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a circle centered at $D$ through $A$ and $B$, it will pass through $C$ as well by Thales's Theorem. Therefore, $DA=DB=DC$ because they are radii of the same circle.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a slight change to the figure.
[image]

Let $E$ be the midpoint of $\overline {BC}.$
$\overline {CE} \cong \overline {EB}.$
$D$ is the midpoint of $\overline {AB}.$
$\overline {BD} \cong \overline {DA}.$
$DE$ is the midline of $\triangle ABC.$
$\overline {DE}$ is parallel to $\overline {AC}.$
$\overline {DE}$ is perpendicular to $\overline {AC}$
$\triangle DEB \cong \triangle DEC$
$\overline {CD} \cong \overline {BD}\cong \overline {AD}$

$\triangle CDA$ and $\triangle CDB$ are isosceles

$\triangle CDB$ is isosceles with a 60 degree angle, making it equilateral.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $sin(30^o)=1/2$   Therefore $BC=BD$ and with an included angle of $60^o$, that triangle is equilateral.  As a result $CD=AD$ and that triangle is isosceles.

Comment: I don't understand how CD= CA ? Can you explain?

Comment: The first triangle is equilateral, so $CD=BD=AD$. Note that I had typos in the original, which have been corrected.

Comment: Oh I thought i read your comment wrong. Thanks !